# Change text in one div by clicking links in another div

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and can't get this to work for my particular situation.

So here's what I want on the page: on one side a `div` with a list of pieces of music (for example, "The Letter - String Quartet"), then on the other side of the page another `div` that will display different text depending on which link has been clicked (so if I clicked "The Letter - String Quartet" in one `div`, it would display a paragraph about that certain piece in the other). I want the `div` displaying info to say something like "Click on a piece to find out more about it" when the page loads.

Comment: I would definitely look into jQuery selectors and click functions, could solve most of this. http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you post some of the code you've got so far, you get faster and more objective answers.

Comment: If we can see a live copy of your code so far, that would be good (readers here frequently encourage posters to demonstrate a good prior attempt, rather than just ask how-would-you-do-this questions). If you don't presently have a host, put the code on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Okay guys, thanks for the responses! Here is my latest attempt, with a bunch of old code one it, too: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BpwCg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to have a click handler on each element that can be clicked on, and have it set the html of the div you want to have show the information.

For example if you do this for Mozart:

```
<a id='mozart'>Mozart</a>
```

and this is your div for displaying text:

```
<div id='displayArea'></div>
```

your jQuery code could look something like:

```
$('#mozart').click(function(e) { 
    $('#displayArea').html("Mozart was a great composer"); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

For further reading:

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll use this as a starting point and go from there. Appreciate the help.